# window.replace method not working in js when I try to insert a URL via rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this piece of javascript to force a browser redirect:

```
window.location.replace("http://google.com")
```

This works fine - however, when I try and populate the URL via my model in rails using;

```
window.location.replace("<%= @link.url %>")
```

it fails because it adds the url onto the end of the link path like `myapp.com/links/google.com`. Not sure why it isn't just replacing the entire URL like when I type it in manually. Any ideas?

Notes: I have a link model with a url attribute and this is on the show page. Further down the page outside of javascript `@link.url` shows the link just fine.

Comment: Because there is the http missing.

Comment: "try to", not "try and". (Sorry I can't help with the Ruby stuff.) (And yes, call me the grammatical Don Quixote...)

Comment: Thanks for the grammar advice.

Comment: You could also get from start correct variable, using object_url method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need add protocol:

```
window.location.replace("http://"+"<%= @link.url %>");
```

Comment: +1 Or even just `window.location.replace("http://<%= @link.url %>");`, since the replacement happens on the server, no need for string concatenation on the client.